# Using while exists in triggers sends the query in infinite loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2014

I created a trigger for insert and it works fine. This creates the trigger just fine:

```
While (exists(Select Id from #temp))
```

But the insert query is going into an infinite loop. I am using while exists to accommodate multiple insertions at a time. Can anyone tell me what is causing the infinite loop?

```
Create Table sqltutorial.Employee
(
     Id int,
     Name nvarchar(50),
     Salary int,
     Gender nvarchar(50),
     DepartmentId int
)

Alter Trigger sqltutorial.trg_forinsert_Employee
on sqltutorial.Employee
For Insert
As
Begin
    print 'Audit Begins'

    Declare @Id int, @Name nvarchar(50), @Salary int,
            @Gender nvarchar(50), @DepartmentId nvarchar(50)
    Declare @AuditText nvarchar(500)

    Select * 
    into #temp 
    from inserted

    While (exists(Select Id from #temp))
        Select @Id = Id from #temp

    Select 
        @Id = Id, @Name = Name, @Salary = Salary,
        @Gender = Gender, @DepartmentId = DepartmentID 
    from 
        #temp

    Set @AuditText = 'New Record Inserted With Id='+Cast(@Id As nvarchar(50))+',Name='+@Name+' ,Salary='+CAST(@Salary as nvarchar(50))+' Gender'+@Gender
                  +' ,Department Id='+@DepartmentId+' on '+CAST((Select GETDATE()) AS nvarchar(50))+' by '+(Select  system_user)

    Insert into sqltutorial.AuditTrial 
    values (@AuditText)

    Delete from #temp 
    where Id = @Id

    print 'Audit Ends'
End
```

Comment: but....there **always** exists a value for `Id` in `#temp`

Comment: I'd say the while just repeats the 'Select @Id=Id from #temp'-statement...

Comment: Also I think a begin / end block for the loop would help things here

Comment: You don't need a while loop at all. You can use something like `INSERT INTO sqltutorial.AuditTrial SELECT CONCAT('Id: ', Id, {etcetera}) FROM inserted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the infinite loop is that you did not specify a `BEGIN` and `END` to your `WHILE` loop code block like this:

```
WHILE SomeCondition = true
  BEGIN

  Do stuff

  END
```

When you use `WHILE` and don't specify `BEGIN..END`, the `WHILE` loop repeats **the next statement only**, over and over until the WHILE condition is no longer met.   And in your code, that would never happen, since the next statement doesn't delete anything from #temp.

In other words, in your code, this is what you are looping:

```
While (exists(Select Id from #temp))
    Select @Id = Id from #temp
```

The rest of the code after this never even executes because the `WHILE` loop never exits.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use all the variables and temp tables in your trigger simply do the following:

```
ALTER TRIGGER sqltutorial.trg_forinsert_Employee
ON sqltutorial.Employee
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO sqltutorial.AuditTrial 
        SELECT  
            ' New Record Inserted With Id=' + CAST([Id] AS NVARCHAR(50)) +
            ',Name=' + [Name] +
            ',Salary=' + CAST(Salary AS NVARCHAR(50)) +
            ',Gender' + Gender +
            ',Department Id=' + DepartmentId + 
            ' on ' + CAST((SELECT GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR(50)) +
            ' by ' + CAST(system_user AS NVARCHAR(256))
        FROM 
            inserted
END
```